# No screenshot sound

Tags: sound, screenshot

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new ASUS Vivobook notepad and I have no confirmation sound when taking screenshots. The file in the `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo` folder with the shutter sound is in place. The web is full of requests on how to eliminate the shutter sound, but I have found none on how to activate it!!

Thanks, John

Comment: in `Settings > Applications > Screenshot` have you got notifications turned ON and `System Sounds` slider set under `Sound`?

Comment: I could not find Screenshot in Settings/Applications. So I opened the package manager and found that gnome-screenshot was not installed (even though I could do screenshots!) and installed it. I can still do screenshots (without shutter sound), and still no Screenshot entry in Settings/Applications. I don't think it should matter but I am using GNOME Classic. Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using GNOME Classic and went back to standard GNOME - I now get the shutter sound. In any case GNOME Classic is completely broken in Ubuntu 22.04 - no drag and drop on the Desktop since this is now done through the DING extension which cannot be added to GNOME Classic. I much prefer the GNOME Classic interface (menus instead of Activity query and fixed sidebar choices) but I guess I will have to adapt.